# Sorting entries in emacs diary file

Tags: emacs

I use emacs diary.

As I append both future plans and daily review in the diary file,
the entries in the file results in not following chronological order.

When I review the diary file at some occasion, I would like to have these entries sorted.
Is there any commands or lisp that I can use to modify the diary file so that the entries get sorted in the chronological order?

Comment: [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) could be used for this kind of thing.

Comment: @BleedingFingers I know that with org-mode I can see the contents of diary with agenda view. The agenda view, however collapse all the content of single entry into one line and thus not really suitable for reviewing, I think. I prefer having entries in the diary file sorted.

Comment: I use `org-sort-entries` for a variety of sorting tasks in the main org-file -- *not* the agenda view.  If you can organize your diary into a main heading with subheadings that need to be organized, then `org-sort-entries` is what you need.  I have it perform multi-sorting:  first sort by alphabetic of the title, second sort by todo state status, third sort by priority, and the final sort is by timestamp.  If you can post a few sample entries of what your diary file looks like, then I or someone else can make a sample function to sort the entries -- please specify the type of sorting desired.

Comment: See also this related thread for using multi-sorting with `org-sort-entries`:  http://superuser.com/a/618244/206164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *icalendar.el*, function *icalendar--datetime-to-iso-date*, change format from *"%d%s%d%s%d"* to *"%04d%s%02d%s%02d"*.

Add this to your initialization:

```
(setq
  diary-date-forms    diary-iso-date-forms
  calendar-date-style 'iso
  )
```

Edit old entries in your *diary-file* to the ISO standard, formatted as above, i.e YYYY/MM/DD.  (The ISO standard is really YYYY-MM-DD).

Now further add this to your initialization:

```
(defun sort--diary (diary-filename)
  (with-current-buffer
    (set-buffer (find-file-noselect (expand-file-name diary-filename)))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\C-j " nil t)
      (replace-match "^j "))
    (sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "^j" nil t)
      (replace-match "\C-j"))
    (save-buffer)))

(defvar sort--diary-filename (expand-file-name diary-file)
  "History for sort--diary diary-filename")

(defun sort-diary (diary-filename)
  "Sort diary file.  Requires dates to use ISO standard"
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer
                      "diary file name: "
                      (car sort--diary-filename)
                      nil nil 'sort--diary-filename)))
  (sort--diary diary-filename))
```

Now you can sort your diary by calling *sort-diary*.

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, I wrote myself a sort function:

```
(defun diary-sort-diary-keyfun nil
  "Key function to order diary entries.
Entries sort in the groups: (days, anniversaries, cyclics, blocks, dates), with any unrecognised
forms before the groups.
Within each group, entries are in ascending date order.
You can prefix entries with `#' to comment them out without affecting sort order.
Prefixing with `&' also does not affect sort order."
  (let ((number "\\s-+\\([0-9]+\\)")
        (months '("Dec" "Nov" "Oct" "Sep" "Aug" "Jul" "Jun" "May" "Apr" "Mar" "Feb" "Jan"))
        (days '("Saturday" "Friday" "Thursday" "Wednesday" "Tuesday" "Monday" "Sunday")))
    (skip-chars-forward "#&")
    (cond
     ((looking-at (concat "%%(diary-block" number number number number number number ")\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "50%04d%02d%02d%04d%02d%02d%s"
              (string-to-number (match-string 3))
              (string-to-number (match-string 2)) (string-to-number (match-string 1))
              (string-to-number (match-string 6))
              (string-to-number (match-string 5)) (string-to-number (match-string 4))
              (match-string 7)))
     ((looking-at (concat "%%(diary-cyclic" number number number number ")\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "40%04d%02d%02d%05d%s"
              (string-to-number (match-string 4))
              (string-to-number (match-string 3)) (string-to-number (match-string 2))
              (string-to-number (match-string 1))
              (match-string 5)))
     ((looking-at (concat "%%(diary-anniversary" number number number ")\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "30%04d%02d%02d%s"
              (string-to-number (match-string 3))
              (string-to-number (match-string 2)) (string-to-number (match-string 1))
              (match-string 4)))
     ((looking-at "%%(\\(.*\\)")        ; after all othe "%%()" rules
      (format "20(%s" (match-string 1)))
     ((looking-at (concat "\\(" (mapconcat 'identity days "\\|") "\\)"
                          "\\( *[0-2 ][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\)?\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "10%d%6s%s"
              (length (member (match-string 1) days))
              (or (match-string 2) "")
              (match-string 3)))
     ((looking-at (concat "\\([0-9]+\\)\\s-+" "\\(" (mapconcat 'identity months "\\|") "\\)"
                          number "\\s-+\\([0-2 ][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\)?\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "60%04d%02d%02d%6s%s"
              (string-to-number (match-string 3))
              (length (member (match-string 2) months))
              (string-to-number (match-string 1))
              (or (match-string 4) "")
              (match-string 5)))
     ((looking-at (concat "\\(" (mapconcat 'identity months "\\|") "\\)"
                          number "," number "\\( *[0-2 ][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\)?\\(.*\\)"))
      (format "60%04d%02d%02d%6s%s"
              (string-to-number (match-string 3))
              (length (member (match-string 1) months))
              (string-to-number (match-string 2))
              (or (match-string 4) "")
              (match-string 5)))
     ((looking-at "[ \t\r]*$")          ; blank line
      (concat "99" (match-string 0)))
     ((looking-at ".*")                 ; last rule
      (concat "00" (match-string 0))))))

(defun diary-sort-diary-file nil
  "Sort the diary entries.
See `diary-sort-diary-keyfun' for the collation sequence."
  (interactive "*")
  ;; sort-order:
  ;; randoms, days, anniversaries, cyclics, blocks, dates
  (goto-char (point-min))
    (let* ((locals-start (and (re-search-forward "\\(\n.*\\)Local variables:\\(.*\n\\)" nil t)
                              (match-beginning 0)))
           (locals-end (and locals-start
                            (search-forward (concat (match-string 1) "End:" (match-string 2)) nil t)
                            (match-end 0)))
           (locals (and locals-start locals-end 
                        (buffer-substring-no-properties locals-start locals-end))))
      (when locals
        (delete-region locals-start locals-end))
      (and (> (point-max) 1)
           (/= (char-after (1- (point-max))) ?\n)
           (goto-char (point-max))
           (insert ?\n))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (sort-subr nil 'forward-line 'end-of-line 'diary-sort-diary-keyfun)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "\n")
      (delete-blank-lines)
      (when locals
        (insert locals))))
```

It's likely that I've assumed European date order, but if you prefer a different order, it shouldn't be hard to adapt it accordingly.

The way it works is that the keyfun returns a string that begins with two digits for the entry type (`00` for unknowns, `10` for day-of-week entries, up to `60` for non-repeating dates), followed by a big-endian representation of the entry, like ISO 8601.

The interactive function, `diary-sort-diary-file`, then uses this keyfun.  It saves any `Local variables` section, reinstating it at the end of the file (this is nice when you've inserted entries from `calendar`, as they get appended).  If you have any `LocalWords` lines (for Ispell), then you could use similar code to keep that intact, or you could adapt the keyfun to place them last.

Sample results (somewhat censored):

> `&Sep 12` Xxxxxxx
>   `&Monday 21:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `#&Thursday` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-float t 0 2)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-float t 6 1)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-phases-of-moon)`
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 26  6 1952)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-anniversary   1  6 1972)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 15  3 1975)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary  7  2 1976)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-anniversary 4 5 1977)` International Star Wars day! :-)
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 13  8 1978)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 26  8 1980)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 16 10 1980)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-anniversary 15  3 2010)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-cyclic 1000  1 6 1972)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-cyclic 1000 13 8 1978)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-cyclic 1000 26 8 1980)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-cyclic  1000  9 9 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  22  3 2013 24  3 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block   6  4 2013  7  4 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `&%%(diary-block 20  4 2013 21  4 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  27  4 2013 28  4 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  18  5 2013 19  5 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block   1  6 2013  2  6 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block   1  6 2013  2  6 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  15  6 2013 16  6 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  22  6 2013 23  6 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  22  6 2013 30  6 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block   6  7 2013  7  7 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  20  7 2013 24  7 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block   9  8 2013 11  8 2013)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  23  4 2016 24  4 2016)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  13  8 2016 21  8 2016)` Xxxxxxx
>   `%%(diary-block  26  8 2016 28  8 2016)` Xxxxxxx
>   `22  Jun 2009 11:30` Xxxxxxx
>   `30  Jun 2009 13:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `&22 Jul 2009` Xxxxxxx
>   `25  Jul 2009` Xxxxxxx
>   `&14 Aug 2009 17:30` Xxxxxxx
>   `&17 Aug 2009` Xxxxxxx
>   `13  Mar 2010` Xxxxxxx
>   `23  Mar 2010 10:50` Xxxxxxx
>   `&17 Jan 2013 14:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `1   Feb 2013` Xxxxxxx
>   `&8  Feb 2013 16:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `12  Feb 2013 18:30` Xxxxxxx
>   `19  Feb 2013 18:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `&12 Mar 2013 10:00` Xxxxxxx
>   `16  Mar 2013` Xxxxxxx
>   `&19 Mar 2013 13:50` Xxxxxxx
>   `20  Mar 2016` Xxxxxxx
>   `2   Apr 2016` Xxxxxxx
>   `18  Jun 2016` Xxxxxxx
>   `17  Jul 2016` Xxxxxxx
>   `12  Nov 2016` Xxxxxxx
>   `28  Mar 2017` Xxxxxxx

---

If you like to keep your diary file organised, you might also like these:

```
(define-generic-mode 'diary-generic-mode
  '(?#)
  nil ;; keywords
  '(("^&.*$" (0 font-lock-comment-face))
    ("^&?\\(%%(diary-[a-z]+[^)]*)\\)" (1 font-lock-type-face t))
    ("^&?[ \t\n]*\\(\\([0-9*]+/[0-9*]+\\(/[0-9*]+\\)?\\|\\(Jan\\(uary\\)?\\|Feb\\(ruary\\)?\\|Mar\\(ch\\)?\\|Apr\\(il\\)?\\|May\\|June?\\|July?\\|Aug\\(ust\\)?\\|Sep\\(tember\\)?\\|Oct\\(ober\\)?\\|Nov\\(ember\\)?\\|Dec\\(ember\\)?\\|\\*\\)\\.?\\s-*[0-3]?[0-9]\\|\\(\\(Mon\\|Tues?\\|Wed\\(nes\\)?\\|Thu\\(rs\\)?\\|Fri\\|Sat\\(ur\\)?\\|Sun\\)\\(day\\)?\\)\\(\\s-[0-9]+\\)?\\)\\(,\\s-+\\(19\\|20\\)[0-9][0-9]\\)?\\s.?\\)" (1 font-lock-type-face t))
    ("^&?\\s-*\\([0-3]?[0-9]\\s-+\\(Jan\\(uary\\)?\\|Feb\\(ruary\\)?\\|Mar\\(ch\\)?\\|Apr\\(il\\)?\\|May\\|June?\\|July?\\|Aug\\(ust\\)?\\|Sep\\(tember\\)?\\|Oct\\(ober\\)?\\|Nov\\(ember\\)?\\|Dec\\(ember\\)?\\)\\s-+[0-9]+\\)" (1 font-lock-type-face t))
    ("[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\(am\\|pm\\)?\\>\\s.?" (0 font-lock-keyword-face t))) ;; font-lock
  '("/diary") ;; auto-mode
  '(diary-mode-setup) ;; function
  "Mode for diary file.")

(defun diary-mode-setup nil
  (set (make-local-variable 'align-rules-list)
       '((date (regexp . "^&?\\([1-3]?[0-9]\\)\\(\\s-+\\)\\(+Jan\\|Feb\\|Ma[ry]\\|Apr\\|Ju[nl]\\|Aug\\|Sep\\|Oct\\|Nov\\|Dec\\)\\(\\s-+\\)[12][90-4][0-9][0-9]")
               (group 2 4)
               (justify . t))
         (block (regexp . "^&?%%(diary-block\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\))")
           (group 1 2 3 4 5 6)
           (justify . t))
         (cyclic (regexp . "^&?%%(diary-cyclic\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\)\\(\\s-+[0-9]+\\))")
           (group 1 2 3 4)
           (justify . t))))
  (set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) t)
  (set (make-local-variable 'version-control) 'never))
```